# Webdriver.io enable flash for selenium-standalone

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, flash, webdriver-io

I'm writing acceptance tests on **node.js** using **webdriver.io** with **selenium standalone server** with latest **Google Chrome driver**.

I need to check that flash elements are clickable, but browser keeps to show me "Restart Chrome to enable Adobe Flash Player".

I've seen [article](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) that shows how to make Chrome driver to see custom profile on local machine, but I can't understand how to use this with my standalone server, since it has poor [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone#example) for configuration.
Can you explain the correct way to enable Adobe flash player for selenium standalone server in webdriver.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. you need to create a custom profile that you will always use to load your chrome with. then you configure the browser like you would do manually too. this means make website exclusions for flash. load some extensions or whatever you want to preconfig. with this code you can do it

```
// setup browser
var options = {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
args: ['user-data-dir=C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 21v69',
'--lang=en']
} //  chromeOptions: {
} // desiredCapabilities: {
} // options = {



var client = webdriverio.remote(options).init();
```

Also here are all command line commands for chrome
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 2):

I found that the following worked:

```
browserName: 'chrome',
 'goog:chromeOptions' : {
            args: ['enable-features=RunAllFlashInAllowMode',
                   'disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission'],
            prefs: {
                "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
                'PluginsAllowedForUrls': '/route/to/site.com'
            }
        }
```

Using ephemeral mode will create a temp profile which allows the prefs to take effect:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3538894?hl=en

'goog:chromeOptions' was introduced as of selenium 3.8 github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/201 –

You can open up the profile which is a JSON blob and see the site added at profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins and profile.content_settings.exceptions.flash_data.

Answer (score 0):

Another workable method. It's possible to allow flash plugin execution in the chrome config
You need to add in the wdio.conf.js three last preferences from code example

```
chromeOptions : {
        args: chromeArgs,
        prefs: {
            "download.default_directory": process.env.PWD +'/download',
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
            "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
            "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1
        }
    }
```

I hope it will helpful